Unexpected View Update Warnings
There are a few questions that mention this warning, but no general solutions or simple examples.
The following code has a main view and a subview with a text field. When clicking the "return" button on the subview, the following warning shows up:
Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.
struct MainView: View {
    @State var showSubView = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showSubView {
                SubView(showSubView: $showSubView)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {

    @Binding var showSubView: Bool
    @State var text: String = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            TextField("", text: $text) // Removing this line removes the warning
            
            Button("Return") {
                showSubView = false
            }
        }
    }
}


The odd part is that when the TextView is removed, this warning doesn't happen, even though text is not linked to MainView. Why is this error happening? Why does adding a TextView cause it?

What platform/OS are you on?

Where is the initial value for text, also you need an else for that if

I'm on XCode 15.4 on MacOS Sonoma. This happens on both my iOS 17 simulator and my iOS 18 physical device.
I filled in the initial value, that was a typo, but I don't believe I need an else since it's in a ZStack

Could not reproduce your warning, all works well for me.
Note, you should use @State private var ....  In MainView you could try adding a view when the showSubView is false, eg
... else { EmptyView() }

There are no @Published in this code so the error must be coming from some other code

@Stoic did you found the solution?
